# Should I use Core Data or Plain SqLite

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I have a big table with 70 rows and 10 columns. It's a table of Saturated Water and Steam that shows different values for different cases. For examle, when temperature is 1 the pressure is 0.006571 and volume is 0.001000, when temperature is 2 then pressure is 0.007060 and volume is 0.001000 and so on.But there's not only temperature, pressure and volume columns, there're more. When,for instance,  I select temperature from pickerlist and enter 2 into the textbox below the it I need to populate corresponding values of the other physical properties to other textboxes in the view.(in this particular case 0.007060 for p and 0.001000 for v). I'm thinking of implementing Core Data for keeping the data. But on the other hand I think SqLite might be more suitable. Anyway I don't know and would like to get your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like this is static data (physical properties of water don't change much), so you may not even need a database, and as Stephen noted, it is not a lot of data.

For a start, you can just save your data in a plist file in your app resources, read it in at launch (or on opening of the relevant screen) and go from there.

Later, if optimization is needed, you can move to Core Data.

Comment: I've also thought about plists before. But I suppose it'd be easier with database to query some value from a row where value for a certain column equals bla bla bla. But I guess I can use NSPredicate object for filtering rows.

Answer (score 2):

Seventy rows and ten columns is not very much data, even for an iOS device. (My app often has thousands of rows for example.)

I would stick with whatever is easiest to develop, which will probably be Core Data.